# Не получается использовать import в NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript

Пишу серверное приложение на TypeScript. Импортирую модули через `import`:

```
import express from 'express'
```

Компилирую код и пытаюсь запускать приложение. Получаю ошибку:

> import express from 'express';
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Нагуглил, что при запуске Ноды нужно добавить `--experimental-modules` и тогда импорты заработают, но они не заработали.

Изменил `import` на `require()` и теперь IDE ругается:

> Cannot find namespace 'express'

Какой выход есть из этой ситуации?

Comment: `import express from 'express'` - так нельзя писать в TS без нужных флагов компилятора, замените на `import * as express`

Comment: @overthesanity пришлите, пожалуйста, ссылку на документацию, где об этом говорится.

Comment: А так `import {express} from 'express'`? Ну и модуль `express` у вас должен быть проинсталлирован в `node_modules`. Иначе писать `./express'`

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin в официальной доке от майкрософт все есть, мне лень щас это искать

Comment: `Similarly a default import (i.e. import d from "foo") for a CommonJS/AMD/UMD module as equivalent to const d = require("foo").default.Most of the CommonJS/AMD/UMD modules available today do not have a default export, making this import pattern practically unusable to import non-ES modules (i.e. CommonJS/AMD/UMD). For instance import fs from "fs" or import express from "express" are not allowed.`

Comment: @overthesanity это всё, конечно, замечательно. В какой гайд не зайду, везде сказано использовать `import express from 'express'` и это вообще единственный способ импорта, на который не ругается компилятор TypeScript.

Comment: покажите гайд, который вы смотрите, я ввел в гугле typescript express и открыл [самую первую ссылку](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/typescript-with-node-and-express-js-why-when-and-how-eb6bc73edd5d), я не вижу import express

Comment: @overthesanity май 2018 года: https://codebrains.io/setting-up-express-with-typescript/ Ноябрь 2018 года: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/11/15/node-express-typescript Ноябрь 2018 года: https://medium.com/@sunnystatue/setup-nodejs-express-typescript-project-enabled-live-edit-when-debugging-4fea0f51dbb3

Comment: в артиклах юзается свойство esModuleInterop, о чем я сразу написал, вы это используете?

Comment: @overthesanity да, это свойство прописано в tsconfig

Comment: хмм, я так понимаю вы только начали проект, вы можете залить его в гитхаб и дать ссылку мне?

Comment: @overthesanity нет, я переписываю проект с закрытым исходным кодом на TypeScript.

Comment: попытайтесь сделать по гайду который я скинул

Comment: Вы мой комментарий видели?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov так делать вообще нельзя.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Почему? Именно так у меня в TypeScript модули и импортируются. Причем декларацию импорта вставляет IDE

Comment: @AntonShchyrov у экспресса нет экспорта `express`

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена явным указанием типа модуля:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "commonjs",
}
```

В таком случае компилятор добавляет в начало файла обёртку для импорта модулей:

```
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

И транспилирует **import** в:

```
const express_1 = __importDefault(require("express"));
```

Что позволяет запускать скомпилированный код в среде NodeJS.

Comment: "вы все по гайду делаете?" @ "да все по ним" :DD

Comment: @overthesanity в TypeScript по умолчанию `--target` равняется `ES3`, а `--module` равняется `target === "ES3" or "ES5" ? "CommonJS" : "ES6"`. Т.е. по умолчанию всё и так должно было компилироваться в commonjs.

Comment: значит у вас стоял таргет не es5, магии не бывает:))